# How to view LaTeX source of equations?

Tags: support, faq-proposed, mathjax

How do you view the source of a question, to see how the LaTeX was specified as markup?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried right-clicking on it and selecting "Show source?"

Comment: You do have to make sure that it was rendered by MathJax, though. Before the site had TeX support, some users would use a rendering engine on another site and link to the generated images.

Comment: doh! never mind. Could one of you admins put this in the faq?

Comment: We need a [status-already-working] :)

Comment: @Jason: Ability to edit the FAQ is "in the works"

Comment: hmmm. I don't want to edit the FAQ directly, but would be willing to propose snippets to add to it.

Comment: Since "right-click" on Windows (with a mouse or trackpad) has different equivalent operations on other operating systems and touchscreen devices, one can see more details on how to pull up the MathJax contextual menu here: [How do I change Math Renderer for MathJax?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30859/915354)

Answer (score 7):

$\text{Steps:} \\ \begin{align}1.& \text{Right click this.} \\ 2. & \text{“Show Math As"} \\ 3. & \text{Click on }\TeX \ Commands. \end{align}$

Comment: Oh man, am I glad this got asked and answered! I just realized how useful this will be!

Comment: This is great--I didn't know about it--but it doesn't work with comments.

Comment: @Mars Actually it works also for comments. You can try it on this formula if you want to test it: $x^2+y^2=z^2$.

Comment: It's not working for me, @MartinSleziak.  Maybe it's browser or OS specific?

Comment: @Mars Here is a post with screenshots if it helps: [How do I view, but not edit, the markup for any given comment on any given StackExchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264440)

Comment: @MartinSleziak--Oh, sorry--it seems to depend on context in ways I don't understand.  Sometimes I have to click on the math expression itself, not just on the comment or answer.  I was misled because for some reason the special popup menu (as opposed to the default browser menu) seems to appear when right-clicking on *any* part of Parth Kohli's answer.  Other answers don't have this property.

Comment: @Mars That's because *all* of this answer is written using MathJax :)

Answer (score 6):

The answers posted so far focus mainly on the source for *one individual formula*.

Another possibility (if you want to copy a large chunk of text with several formulas) is to click on edit (and, of course, not save the edits you make, just copy the part you need).

If you do not want to click on edit - to make sure that you do not change something by mistake - you can still get to the source through the [revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/revisions-list/info). You can get to the revision history easily if the post has been edited at least once - just click on the timestamp saying "edited Date". If the post wasn't edited, you can use the button next to the post to [display the timeline](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24826/how-to-see-questions-time-line) and then manually change the `timeline` to `revisions` in the URL.

Viewing source of the webpage also sometimes works (View/Source in Internet Explorer, Ctrl+U in Mozilla Firefox). This way has some flaws - you don't see markup, but html. If TeX-contains & (ampersound) it is changed.

---

The above is explicitly about getting the MathJax source *from a post*. (This is what was actually asked in the question.) There were a few comments asking how to view the source *in comments*. For this, see: [Seeing the MathJax mark-up for a comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26901) and [How to copy mixture of text and latex formulas in a comment?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3234) (Although *some* of the suggestions given in the answers to this question - namely using MathJax menu and displaying source of the website - work for comments, too.)

Comment: If you want to cut and paste the entire source code of somebody else's comments, including all the latex, view source seems to be the only method.

Comment: Also a bookmarklet mentioned [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3234/how-to-copy-mixture-of-text-and-latex-formulas-in-a-comment/16530#16530) could be used. The link in that post is now that, but you can recover that bookmarklet, for example, [from Wayback Machine](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/25175/save-the-answer-in-tex-pdf-revisioned#comment98926_25175). (Perhaps we should collect somewhere the bookmarklets which were on that site - at least some of them are often handy.)

Comment: To be more specific, you could try [this](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://normalhuman.github.io/stackmarklets/) to see for the whole collection and probably you should also be able copy individual bookmarklets from there.

Comment: Edit isn't an option for comments.

Comment: @Mars The question explicitly asks about LaTeX source *in a question*. If you are interested in comments, you can look at [How to copy mixture of text and latex formulas in a comment?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3234) and some of the posts [linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3234). (And, in fact, the other method - viewing source - does work for comments.)

Answer (score -4):

First, decide if you...

1. want to view the $\mathcal{MathJax}$ source code for one short simple equation such as $f(x) = 5*x^{2} + 72$
2. want to view the $\mathcal{MathJax}$ source code for an entire stack exchange question or answer.

#### How to View $\mathcal{MathJax}$ Source for a Single Short Equation

Right-click on the equation with your computer mouse and select
$\qquad$ <kbd>**Show Math As**</kbd> → <kbd>**$TeX$ commands**</kbd>

$\begin{aligned} 63_{10} &= \displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{5}} \\
                         &= \begin{pmatrix}2^{5}+2^{4}+2^{3}+2^{2}+2^{1}+2^{0}\end{pmatrix}_{10} \\ 
&= 111111_{2} \\ \end{aligned}$

[image: SCREEN CAPTURE OF A MATHJAX FORMULA AND THE CONTEXT MENU]

#### How to View $\mathcal{MathJax}$ Source for a An Entire Question or Answer

1. Look at the URL (web address) at the the top of your web-browser

[image: screen capture of a URL box]

2. Delete everything from the URL to the right of `questions/65992` The number `65992` might be different for you.
3. Type `revisions` or `/revisions` at the end of the URL. Do not forget the letter "**`s`**" at the end of `revisions`. The result will look something like:

$\qquad\quad$ `https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/659/revisions`

4. press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key on your keyboard.
5. Copy and paste the mark-down language source code of the question or answer.