# How to see questions time line?

Tags: support, timeline

How can I see question timeline? For example, when it is reviewed when it get an answer when it is vote up. And if I can't see it yet in which reputation I can? Because when I do it it doesn't work.

Comment: in fact this information is in the tag-wiki of the tag you used. But I did not know either until after having written the answer.

Comment: Yes I was mistaking about posts and questions and I want to ask it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The URL of the timeline of a post {PostID} is

```
http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/{PostID}/timeline
```

To get the PostID you can use the share link, it is the first number in that URL (the second, if it exists, is your UserID). For a question-post you can usually just get the PostID from the address bar of your browser, too.
Yet, note for the timeline it is `/posts/` not `/questions/`; hence it does not suffice just to append `/timeline`.

Comment: Oh yes thanks I was mistaking that.

Comment: I see, this answer my other question.

Answer (score 22):

As of January 16, 2020, all questions and answers have a “timeline button” underneath the voting buttons. Clicking on the clock icon directly leads to the timeline for that question or answer:

[image]

For more information, see the announcement [Add a link to the timeline of a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post/342316#342316) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

As the other answer and also [the tag-info](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/timeline/info) say, timeline can be found by modifying the url to the form `http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/id/timeline`.

Rather easy way to get there is to go to revisions first - by clicking the timestamp of the last edit - and then change the word `revisions` to `timeline` in the url. (Although it only works for edited posts.)

For example, for your question if you click on the timestamp of the last edit, you get this url: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/24826/revisions After changing url you get timeline: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/24826/timeline

Here is a picture illustrating this. I took the picture from this post: [Is it possible to rollback my posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101596/is-it-possible-to-rollback-my-posts/101598#101598)

[image: Timestamp]

I will also mention that there is a feature request on meta.SE: [Add a link to the timeline of a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post) This feature request is marked [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred).

Comment: except when a post has no revisions, then you edit both questions and append timeline instead of the question.

Comment: Just to note, the feature request mentioned at the end is now [status-completed]. [Martin R's answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31157/915354) here also mentions this, with added details.

Answer (score 2):

The [SE Modifications](http://rchern.github.io/StackExchangeScripts/readme.html) is a userscript which modifies sites on the Stack Exchange network in a variety of ways.  One of the modifications is to provide a link to the timeline in the same cluster of links as the "share", "edit", etc links.