# My flag was considered disputed, but the post still got put on hold. What did I do wrong?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flagged [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2962798/%CE%B2%E2%88%88c-is-algebraic-of-degree-n-that-is-there-exists-a-polynomial-p%E2%88%88pnc-of-degr) and I got the message that [my flag suggestion was considered disputed](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/395099?group=1&status=4). But as you can see from the post, the post was put on hold in the end and I do not really understand that because I thought I did the right action.

Could you tell me what I did wrong here? And what could I have done instead?

This question might be stupid but I do not have much experience with flagging posts yet. Thanks for your understanding!

Comment: You did nothing wrong, and your effort expedited the closure of this bare "problem statement question".  The only thing I would have done differently is to leave a Comment for the OP explaining the importance of sharing their approach, e.g. so that Readers have a better understanding of what kind of help is needed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First note, this is an automatic reply. No human treated this flag directly.

The issue is that the initial review got 3 looks okay and 2 close, thus the "low quality" of the post was disputed.

The ensuing close review then led to the closure. But this does not affect the status of the flag retroactively. (Maybe it should.)

Generally you might flag this rather as "should be closed" than as "low quality," yet also there you might run into the same issue that the initial flags is disputed, but then it still gets closed down the road.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Could you tell me where I can see that the initial review got 3 "looks okay" and 2 "close"?

Comment: @Diglett If you look at the [timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2962798/timeline) of the post you can see there all reviews for that post that have *already been finished.* (See also: [How to see questions time line?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24826))

Comment: @quid: Thank you! I will take your advice into consideration the next time.