# A math question with lot of views but why?

Tags: discussion

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3335454/how-many-ways-can-i-go-from-1-to-10-in-the-following-diagram/3335456#3335456) is a math question I answered which has a lot upvotes. I think that is because there a lot of views ($1k$) but it haven't got any bounty. Why?

Comment: Perhaps it was on the [Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot)?

Comment: But how does the question goes in hot network question?

Comment: I think [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/what-are-the-criteria-for-questions-to-be-selected-for-hot-network-questions/61343#61343) is relevant

Comment: Maybe the tag ([meta-tag:hot-questions-list]) could be added to this question - now that it's been clarified that it has to do with this topic.

Comment: As far as why a Question has a bounty offered, this happens when a user [decides to offer a bounty](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).  Reasons for offering a bounty vary, but the effect is that reputation points are deducted from the user who *offers* the bounty and are intended to be awarded to one of the users who provides an Answer that the *offerer* deems worthy.

Comment: You post this answer on your profile and now on Meta so I guess that increases the number of views.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the question was in the hot network questions list. This can be confirmed by checking [the revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3335454/revisions)<sup>1</sup> or [the timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3335454/timeline).<sup>2</sup> (You can also notice that after some time it was removed from the HNQ list by a moderator.<sup>3</sup>)

About your additional question [in a comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30680/a-math-question-with-lot-of-views-but-why#comment134077_30680): How does a question get into the HNQ list? The details are rather complicated, but if you are really interested, a good place to start might be [this post on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/what-are-the-criteria-for-questions-to-be-selected-for-hot-network-questions/61343#61343).

<sup>1</sup>This feature was implemented an the end of February 2019, for older questions you cannot find out in this way whether they were in the HNQ list. See also: [Now you can know if a question really hit the HNQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324641)

<sup>2</sup>See also: [How to see questions time line?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24826)

<sup>3</sup>The possibility that moderators can remove posts from the HNQ list is relatively recent, too. There is an ongoing discussion related to this feature on this site: [Under what criteria should we remove questions from the HNQ list?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30671)