# Seeing the MathJax mark-up for a comment

Tags: support, mathjax, comment

If a question contains some useful MathJax mark-up that I don't know and want to recycle for use elsewhere, I can "edit" the question, copy the mark-up I want and then cancel my "edit". This isn't an option if I want to see the mark-up used in a comment. Is there a way of seeing the MathJax original source for a commment?

Comment: Hover over the mathjaxed-portion in which you are interested, and right click: you can then select "Show math as:" and a menu appears from which you select "Tex commands." A small pop-up window will appear with all the formatting, minus the dollar-signs.

Comment: Cool! As a Mac user, I have to translate that into Ctrl+click, but it works a treat. If you'd care to turn your comment into an answer, I will happily give it the green tick.

Comment: Sure.  Just did so.

Comment: Looking at the comment in the mobile app also works. In there, mathjax in comments *only* shows up as code!

Comment: @GTonyJacobs: you are quite right. 10/10 to you for lateral thinking! I'm not sure the mobile app deserves any points. $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: See also [How to copy mixture of text and latex formulas in a comment?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3234) (There is a useful bookmarklet mentioned in one of the answers - notice that the link is outdated, but you can find a new link in the comments.) Some [other posts linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3234) can be useful, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hover over the mathjaxed-portion in which you are interested, and right click: you can then select "Show math as:" and a menu appears from which you select "Tex commands." A small pop-up window will appear with all the formatting, minus the dollar-signs.

Disclaimer: I'm a windows-user, so I'm hoping this can be modified for mac users!

From the OP: Windows right-click is equivalent to Ctrl+click on a Mac.

Comment: If there are several formulas and you do not want to copy then one by one, some possibilities are suggested here: [How to copy mixture of text and latex formulas in a comment?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3234)

Comment: Apologies for taking so long to give you the tick. I don't know what happened at the time. $\ddot{\frown}$.

Comment: No problem, @RobArthan.