# Mathjax format for combinatorials

Tags: support, mathjax

Could someone direct me to a source that explains how to format combinatorial expressions, eg rCn in Mathjax?
Like.

n
r

thanks
            ralph

Comment: You can use commands such as `$\binom{n+1}k` $\binom{n+1}k$, `$\dbinom{n+1}k` $\dbinom{n+1}k$, `$\tbinom{n+1}k` $\tbinom{n+1}k

Comment: BTW in case of problems with MathJax, you're welcome to ask also in the [MathJax chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/13752/2020/2/9).

Answer (score 13):

You have asked specifically about [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). They can be typeset using `\binom` or `\choose`. Examples: `$\binom{m+n}{k+1}$` $\binom{m+n}{k+1}$ or `${m+n \choose k+1}$` ${m+n \choose k+1}$. In the case of choose do not forget to include curly brackets around the binomial coefficient. The command \binom comes also with two size modifications: `$\dbinom{m+n}{k+1}$` $\dbinom{m+n}{k+1}$ and `$\tbinom{m+n}{k+1}$` $\tbinom{m+n}{k+1}$. (Using \dbinom in titles is discouraged because it makes the vertical size too big: [Guidelines for good use of $\rm\LaTeX$ in question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9687).)

You can typeset [multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_coefficient) in a similar way: `$\binom n{k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_m}$` $\binom n{k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_m}$.

On Wikipedia, some common symbols used in combinatorics are listed in the article [List of mathematical symbols by subject § Combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols_by_subject#Combinatorics) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_mathematical_symbols_by_subject&oldid=936745833#Combinatorics)). The article also briefly mentions LaTeX syntax. Among the symbols linked there you have factorial and its modification, it this case the syntax is clear: `$n!$` $n!$, `$n!!$` $n!!$, `$!n$` $!n$. For [multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_coefficient), Wikipedia uses 
`$\left(\!\!\binom nk\!\!\right)$` $\left(\!\!\binom nk\!\!\right)$ and it seems that there are also [posts on this site](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cleft(%5C!%5C!%5Cbinom%20nk%5C!%5C!%5Cright)%24&p=1) which use the same notation. 
The Wikipedia article also mentions [falling and rising factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials): `$n^{\overline{m}}$` $n^{\overline{m}}$ and `$n^{\underline{m}}$` $n^{\underline{m}}$. And also [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) `$n\#$` $n\#$.

Another symbol in combinatorics I am able to think of is the symbol for [Stirling numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number): `$\left[{n \atop k}\right]$` $\left[{n \atop k}\right]$ and `$\left\{\begin{matrix} n \\ k \end{matrix}\right\}$` $\left\{\begin{matrix} n \\ k \end{matrix}\right\}$.

This is what I was able to think of from the top of my head - with some help of Wikipedia. (I am sure that people who are more experienced both in combinatorics and in LaTeX can add a lot of further details.)

One way, which might often help to find appropriate MathJax/LateX syntax, could be checking how the things are typeset in other posts on this site. (For example, in this case you could have looked at the posts tagged [binomial-coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binomial-coefficients). See also: [How to view LaTeX source of equations?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/659).) And also if you can find a corresponding article on Wikipedia and if the symbols/formulas are typeset there using `<math>..</math>`, the same syntax is very likely to work in MathJax/LaTeX. (To view source code of the Wikipedia article, you can simply click on edit.)