# Requesting New Feature: "View Mark-up" button

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, markdown

Beneath every answer on stack exchange, there are various hyperlinks, such as:

- *Share*
- *Edit*
- *Follow*
- *Flag*

Occasionally, I want to copy a snippet mark-up language from an answer without editing that answer.

For years, I have clicked the "*edit*" link, copied the piece of mark-up language I wanted, and then closed clicked the "*cancel changes*" button.

However, I occasionally get an error message which says something like:

> SUGGESTED EDITS ARE NOT ALLOWED
>
> [image: SCREEN CAPTURE OF "SUGGESTED EDITS ARE NOT ALLOWED"]

It would be nice if users could view the mark-up language without editing it.

I especially like to copy and paste source code for [$\mathtt{MathJax}$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and $\LaTeX$

The resulting webpage could look almost the same as the "*edit answer*" dialog, except that instead of...

- "save edits"
- "cancel"

... we could have a "close" button

Also, the text "Edit" can be replaced with "View Mark-up "

[image: screen capture of "save edits" button]

Comment: If you are primarily concerned with copying mathjax code, you can right click on it and use the mathjax menu to copy the code (Show Math as $\to$ TeX commands).

Comment: Interestingly, this feature request on [meta.se] is marked as (status-completed): [View Source link on all questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24400). So is this one: [View source link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68731) There is also a related older post on this meta: [How to view LaTeX source of equations?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/659)

Answer (score 3):

I do agree with your feature suggestion, but as the post with the suggestion on Meta.SE has somehow been marked as [status-completed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed), I don't know if it will come.

> It would be nice if users could view the mark-up language without editing it.

This is actually already possible via the links that Martin posted in the comments, but it takes a couple more clicks, if the post has at least one edit. (A post with no edits requires you to type instead of click, see bullet point below.) But this method even lets you see the source for any revision of the post, not just the current version. For reference I took a couple screenshots of this question to explain the process:

1. If the post has been edited, click on the "edited on DATE at TIME by X" to see the revision history

> [image]

- If there have been no edits, modify the URL as follows. Example URL: `https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33731/requesting-new-feature-view-mark-up-button`

   A. remove everything after the post ID:

  `https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33731/`

   B. change "questions" to "posts":

  `https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/33731/`

   C. add `revisions` to the end:

  `https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/33731/revisions`

  which gives [the same link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/33731/revisions) as the above.

2. At any revision that modified the post (including the original posting), there will be a button to view the source:

> [image]

Clicking it reveals the source in plain-text. For instance, I now know that you used `+`s for bullet points,

```
Beneath every answer on stack exchange, there are various hyperlinks, such as:  
+ *Share*  
+ *Edit*   
+ *Follow*     
+ *Flag*

...
```

- For answers that have not been edited, you need to find the post ID e.g. via the "Share" button. Clicking on  "Share" for this answer gives `https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/33739/80734`. The first number `33739` is this answer's post ID (the second number is my user ID.) Now replace the post ID in the above to get [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/33739/revisions).

Comment: Concerning the modification of the links, a bit faster way is to click on the timeline icon (which is always present) and then change `timeline` to `revisions` in the URL. See also: [How to see questions time line?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24826)